# Handler Performance Overhead

Tags: android, handler

I'm designing an app that plots real time data. I periodically poll the value of a variable in the activity from within a `Runnable` and send that value off to be plotted using OpenGL.

I'm currently using a `Handler` to periodically execute the `Runnable` (say at 100ms intervals). Since I don't need access to the UI thread, i.e., OpenGL renders on a separate thread, is a `Handler` the best method to use in terms of performance? Would I be better off using something else like a `ScheduledExecutorService` or even just a `Runnable` with a `sleep` and appropriate `wait` and `notify` calls to handle lifecycle events?

Comment: a simple thread looping would be simpler and more efficient

Comment: you should use Timer because when you no need it more you can easily cancel the timer by calling its cancel() method.

Comment: Thanks njzk. So you would suggest a Runnable with a `while(true)` (properly set up with `breaks` etc.) and appropriate `wait` and `notify` calls?

Comment: Thanks Biraj. Yes, but I can do that with a `synchronized` runnable and an appropriate flag system. It's just whether this will give better performance over a `Timer`, or probably better `ScheduledExecutorService`